# How would I apply the remainder/modulus operator here?

Tags: c, math, modulus

This isn't a straight up programming question, in the sense that it's not about specific code, but this does involve the remainder/modulus operator.

I have a formula for an even input value and a different one for an odd input value, but in my program, I need to somehow combine these two so that I get one formula that works for both even and odd inputs.

****(I have two integer values, x and y, when I say an even input value, I mean that when you add x and y, the number is an even number; and same for odd inputs)**

Formula for even value: 1 + sqrt(((x - 10)^2) + ((y - 10)^2))

Formula for an odd value: 1 + (((abs(x - 10)) + (abs(y - 10)))/(2))

I did notice that these two formulas are very similar and I asked my professor about this problem, and he did hint at using the remainder/modulus operator.

At first, I thought about dividing both formulas by 2 and then adding them both together, so that one of the values would be 0, thus, only using one of the formulas. But when I plugged in values, I realized that the answer for an even input is not always even. So now I'm not sure how I would go about solving this.

Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Here are some values:

[image: Table of Values]

NOTE: The y value isn't limited to 10, I just used 10 so that I could calculate the values by hand easier.

Comment: It's not very clear what the algorithm/program/function is supposed to do. Could you show some example input and output?

Comment: Sure Juhana! I'll put up some values I got and Gangadhar, I need to figure this step out before I can start coding. (I need the formula first so that I can translate it into c)

Comment: In what sense are the formulas similar? (The first has a square root and the second not, ...) - And what do you mean by "combining the two"? Is `if ((x+y) % 2 == 0) { ... } else { ... }` good enough?

Comment: Martin R: The second formula seems to have almost exactly the same content, just has the absolute values and divided by 2. Whereas, the first formula has that square root, but the content is similar. And I agree with using if/else statements, but my professor said that we aren't allowed to use them. :( Which is why I'm so confused by this problem. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have “if x + y is odd then a(x, y) else b(x, y)“, you can translate this into a formula using the modulus operator like this:

```
((x + y)%2) * a(x, y) + (1 - (x + y)%2) * b(x, y)
```

One parenthesis will be zero, the other one, depending on which case you are in. I can't imagine a useful application for this, though, particularly not in C. In vectorized languages like R, there might be some motivation for this kind of code.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry but a question, so would a(x, y) and b(x, y) be my two formulas?

Comment: @Karen: Right, I used them as placeholders so I wouldn't have to type all that stuff.